# How do I suppress knit2pdf LaTeX output in the R console

Tags: r, knitr

When running `knit2pdf()`, it does not suppress the LaTeX output when using `quiet = TRUE` within the R console. I am running `knitr v1.11`. A simple example would be:

### test.Rnw file

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
some stuff
\end{document}
```

### R Code

```
knitr::knit2pdf(input = "./test.Rnw", quiet = TRUE)
```

### Output to R console:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\size12.clo))
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty))))
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\color.sty (C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg
)) (C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\framed\framed.sty) (C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\alltt.sty)
 (C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\upquote\upquote.sty) (test.aux)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) [1{C:/Users/neastwood1/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(test.aux) )<C:/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 10374 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\size12.clo))
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty))))
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\graphics\color.sty (C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg
)) (C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\framed\framed.sty) (C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\alltt.sty)
 (C:\MiKTeX\tex\latex\upquote\upquote.sty) (test.aux)
(C:\MiKTeX\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) [1{C:/Users/neastwood1/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(test.aux) )<C:/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 10374 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
[1] "test.pdf"
```

### Session Info:

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                            LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.11

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.2  RODBC_1.3-12
```

My wish is to stop this output from returning to the console. I have thought about maybe running a call to `knit2pdf` using a shell command and piping the output to `>NUL` but I am not sure if this would be wise or easy to do?

Comment: Using RStudio and Compile PDF, nothing shows in the console, but you can open the Log to see the output.  Not sure this helps you.

Comment: Please include the output of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Added `sessionInfo()`. @lawyeR I am running `knit2pdf()` from within a function so I am not using the Compile PDF button.

Comment: Just for the record, this was cross-posted at https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1108

Comment: FYI, it has since come to my attention that the texi2dvi.exe has been removed from MiKTeX. The R Core team are aware of this and it is just easier to use `latemk -quiet` for now.